# Encountering Error in Token Swap: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED Slippage

Tags: txpool

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to execute a token swap using the contract function `swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens`.

The transaction reverted with the `error message: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED Slippage`.

Could someone please explain what this error means and provide guidance on how to resolve it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.